# Resizing background to match text

Tags: html, css, background, resize

I am quite new to CSS and HTML so please excuse the noobness.

What I am trying to do is to **get the main area of my website to resize according to the amount of text it contains in it**. I have searched and searched, but have been unable to find suitable answers. One thing I have tried is putting each of the 'sections' into a table, but I could not get it to work.

Any help is greatly appreciated thanks!

Due to posting restrictions I am unable to post the image directly:
http://img402.imageshack.us/img402/6084/sitevuc.png

Here is the HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="main"><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p></div>
<div id="footer"></div>
</body>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
#header {
    background: url(images/bg_pages.png) repeat-x;
    min-height: 973px;
    min-width: 1680px;  

}

#main {
    background:#fff;    
    min-height: 100px;
    min-width: 1680px;

}

#footer {
    background:url(images/footer_pages.png);
    min-height: 51px;
    min-width: 1680px;

}
```

Comment: Can you please post the HTML and CSS that you are currently working with?

Comment: You're asking for the coding of an entire layout. Just Google, how to create a simple layout with Div's. Do not ever use a table for layout.

Comment: No, I have a layout already, but thought I would simplify it for the purposes of this so I could get a better understanding. 

Oh ok, thanks! I'll stick with DIV's then, but still the issue is present that the 'main' div will not adjust to accommodate its contents?

Comment: it should adjust automatically when you start to write content within your div.

Comment: Also using min-height and min-width isn't such a good thing. This is not compatible with earlier versions of IE.

Comment: Writing content in the DIV creates a line row between the content and the header.

I saw that when I tried validating :( Is there a way around that?

Comment: Thanks Michael for all the help, but I got it sorted! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

Here's a few lines of CSS that do the trick.  Found this just a few days ago.